# ruby how to remove elements from hash array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, hashmap

I am trying to remove the entire row for `id` and `name` for `001` and `002`from the sample:

```
sample = [{"id"=>"000", "name"=>"Bob"},
     {"id"=>"001", "name"=>"Sally"},
     {"id"=>"002", "name"=>"Spike"},
     {"id"=>"003", "name"=>"Junior"},
     {"id"=>"004", "name"=>"Tater"}]

remove_ele = ["001","002"]
```

I have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work:

`sample.delete_if { |key, value| sample[x]["id"] == remove_ele[x] }`

essentially, i'm trying to compare the 2 and any matches in `remove_ele` it will just delete the entire row/element in `sample`.

Please assist in best way to do this in ruby.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there are a few problems with this block you've provided to `delete_if`:

```
sample.delete_if { |key, value| sample[x]["id"] == remove_ele[x] }
```

Since `sample` is an array of hashes, using the `delete_if` iterator will pass a hash to the block. I.e. it should be `|hash|` instead of `|key, value|`.

Secondly, `x` will not be defined in your block.

A functional solution would be this:

```
remove_ele.each do |id_to_remove|
  sample.delete_if { |hash| hash['id'] == id_to_remove }
end
```

Alternatively, which does the same thing:

```
sample.delete_if { |hash| remove_ele.include? hash['id'] }
```

Comment: Upvotted because you provided explanation with your code!

Answer (score 1):

`sample.delete_if {|x| remove_ele.include? x['id'] }`

Comment: Down voted due to lack of explanation. Providing the code without explanations does nothing for the op